# DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs.PropertyDescriptor is of what type?

Tags: c#, wpf, propertyinfo, propertydescriptor

I'm new to WPF, and I'm trying to customize a bit a dataGrid to show data in a readable way. I've seen [this article](http://code.cheesydesign.com/?p=701), and I wonder - at the end there is a cast of the `PropertyDescriptor` property into two classes, using the `as` key word, and a small check code. What's the difference between `PropertyDescriptor` and `PropertyInfo` classes? why are both used?

Answer (score 0):

you can refer to below answer for differentiating between the two

[Difference between ComponentModel reflection (e.g PropertyDescriptor) and standard reflection (e.g PropertyInfo)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301356/difference-between-componentmodel-reflection-e-g-propertydescriptor-and-standa)

Comment: You could just answer the question!

Comment: @StephenFoster Thats correct, unfortunately it is an old post and I was new to SO. Wanted to put this in comment to help the OP and avoid copy-pasting the exact answer, but I guess I didn't have much repo to comment at that time.